# Is anyone using XForms in their web applications?

Tags: w3c, xforms

A few years ago we started playing around with [XForms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/) from the W3C for a web app which required hundreds of custom forms.

As they aren't currently supported natively by the major browsers, what parsers/tools are you using on your projects today?

I'm not really interested in plugins - this needs to be something server side that emulates XForms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use XForms for creating user interfaces for SOAP-based web services. Currently we settled with **Chiba** XForms engine (http://chiba.sourceforge.net/), but **Orbeon** ([http://www.orbeon.com/](http://www.orbeon.com)) actually seems more mature. Both are server-side engines, which convert XForms into HTML on the fly. The validation is performed on server side with the help of AJAX. This puts quite high demands on the server, so I wouldn't bet on those engines when creating sites with heavy traffic. Alternatives are well documented on XForms Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms.

Comment: Any experience with overriding the view that those engine generates ? or is there any converter available for XForm -> HTML

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to convert XForms to XHTML+Javascript with just an XSLT transformation so it can be done on client-side without plug-in. Have a look at http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms/. It's an opensource project : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltforms

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've understood, XForms is a natural fit to the current flavour of REST-based architectures while addressing most of the major issues with complex form development in a pretty neat way.

It's sad that people have largely forgotten about it :(

That said, there are Javascript-based xforms engines like [Ubiquity](http://code.google.com/p/ubiquity-xforms/) that would help in getting cross-browser xforms support. And the recent development of high-performance Javascript VM's would give such engines great performance as well.

Answer (score -2):

I do not use them and as they are not supported by any major browsers I doubt that anybody else will use them very often either.

Comment: He's got a point. This is what started the HTML 5 effort (as "Web Forms 2" by Opera Software).

Comment: Engines like Orbeon and Chiba transform serverside xforms to html and javascript - there's no need for browser support.

Comment: Until now i didn't find anything else to compete with xforms when we need to edit large forms with a lot of fields related to each other.